# Groupby and filter rows based on a custom logic

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe given below:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"timestamp": [pd.Timestamp(2016, 7, 29), pd.Timestamp(2017, 8, 22), pd.Timestamp(2017, 10, 9), pd.Timestamp(2018, 1, 9), pd.Timestamp(2018, 3, 31), pd.Timestamp(2018, 7, 5),pd.Timestamp(2018, 8, 5), pd.Timestamp(2018, 9,5), pd.Timestamp(2018, 11, 6),pd.Timestamp(2018, 12, 6), pd.Timestamp(2018, 12, 8)], "userId": [1, 2, 2, 2, 2,2,3, 4, 4, 4,4 ], "movieId": [111065, 35455, 132531, 132531, 2863, 132531, 4493, 133813,8888, 133813,133813], "rating":[3,4,5,2,4,3, 2,2 ,3,1, 3]
               })
```

[image]

I want to first group by the "userId" column and then for each group remove rows wherever the "movieId" has consecutive duplications. To illustrate better, this is how the end Dataframe should like : (the red rows should be filtered out)

[image]

I tried a groupby and filter technique with custom function in lambda, however that doesn't retain all the columns. Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"timestamp": [pd.Timestamp(2016, 7, 29), pd.Timestamp(2017, 8, 22), pd.Timestamp(2017, 10, 9), pd.Timestamp(2018, 1, 9), pd.Timestamp(2018, 3, 31), pd.Timestamp(2018, 7, 5),pd.Timestamp(2018, 8, 5), pd.Timestamp(2018, 9,5), pd.Timestamp(2018, 11, 6),pd.Timestamp(2018, 12, 6), pd.Timestamp(2018, 12, 8)], "userId": [1, 2, 2, 2, 2,2,3, 4, 4, 4,4 ], "movieId": [111065, 35455, 132531, 132531, 2863, 132531, 4493, 133813,8888, 133813,133813], "rating":[3,4,5,2,4,3, 2,2 ,3,1, 3]
               })
df1['match'] = df1.movieId.eq(df1.movieId.shift())
df1 = df1[df1['match']==False]

print(df1)
```

Let me know if this helps you

Answer (score 2):

Try [`.drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html#pandas-dataframe-drop-duplicates):

```py
df1 = df1.drop_duplicates(subset=["userId", "movieId"], keep="first")
print(df1)
```

Prints:

```
   timestamp  userId  movieId  rating
0 2016-07-29       1   111065       3
1 2017-08-22       2    35455       4
2 2017-10-09       2   132531       5
4 2018-03-31       3     4493       4
5 2018-07-05       4   133813       3
```

Comment: This works but this would miss out an edge case (not shown in the above image) : only consecutive duplicates need to be removed; normal duplications in (userId & movieId) is acceptable

Comment: @xerxes01 Can you please edit your question and put the example input and expected output there?

Comment: Hi Andrej, I have edited the question. Would be really grateful if you could pitch in!